Does the standard specify when function template instantiation side-effects are visible?
Note that I am not asking "When do function templates get instantiated?" Rather, "When are the side-effects of that instantiation visible?"
An example of a side-effect of an instantiation would be friend injection. For instance:
// Same result on Clang, GCC, and MSVC.

template<int N>
struct FriendIndex {
    friend constexpr bool Get(FriendIndex);
};

template<int N, bool val>
struct FriendInjector {
    friend constexpr bool Get(FriendIndex<N>) {
        return true;
    }
};

template <bool val>
auto InstantSideEffect() {
    (void)FriendInjector<0, val>{};
    return 0;
}

template <bool val>
int DelayedSideEffect() {
    (void)FriendInjector<1, val>{};
    return 0;
}

int dummy0 = InstantSideEffect<true>();
// Will succeed.
static_assert(Get(FriendIndex<0>{}),"");

int dummy1 = DelayedSideEffect<true>();
// Will fail: Get(FriendIndex<1>) is not a constant expression.
static_assert(Get(FriendIndex<1>{}),"");

By instantiating InstantSideEffect<true>(), the constexpr friend function Get(FriendIndex<0>) is defined right after instantiation, and can be used in static_assert.
On the other hand, by instantiating DelayedSideEffect<true>(), the definition of Get(FriendIndex<1>) is not visible right after instantiation, and static_assert using it will fail to compile.
Since the only difference between the two functions is that InstantSideEffect() returns auto and DelayedSideEffect() returns int, I looked at the standard to see if it had any info about auto affecting when these side-effects are visible.
The draft C++14 standard, says in 7.1.6.4 [dcl.spec.auto]/12:

Return type deduction for a function template with a placeholder in its declared type occurs when the definition is instantiated even if the function body contains a return statement with a non-type-dependent operand. [ Note: Therefore, any use of a specialization of the function template will cause an implicit instantiation. Any errors that arise from this instantiation are not in the immediate context of the function type and can result in the program being ill-formed. — end note ]

This makes it sound like auto affects instatiations for specialized function templates, and that auto possibly affects SFINAE. However, I don't see anything in the standard specifying when side-effects are visible.
Is there some part of the standard that touches on when side-effects like friend injection are visible? Or is it just a coincidence that the three big compilers make friend injections instantly visible for auto function templates, and that could change at any time?

The standard very much wants the question not to come up, although not every relevant case is IFNDR (yet).

side effects appear at the point of instantiation, i.e. at dummy1 definition. And the Get(FriendIndex<1>) is actually injected, but it's not constexpr

@DavisHerring Could you elaborate on "not every relevant case is IFNDR (yet)"? The only movement I saw was stagnating objection to friend injection from 9 years ago (https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue2118). Are there any new developments?

@Gene If Get(FriendIndex<1>) is being injected at instantiation, just not constexpr, why would Get(FriendIndex<0>)'s injection be constexpr?

@Joshua Maiche -- for Get(FriendIndex<1>) to be a constant expression, it needs to be fully instantiated and available at compile time before static_assert. I'm actually not sure if instantiation is delayed to the end.

@Gene Sorry if my question wasn't clear, but that's what it intended to ask. When do injections like Get(FriendIndex<0>) become available in function templates, why do auto-returning functions change when these injections are available, and is there anything in the standard that indicates why this is happening?

@Joshua Maiche -- you have two places where Get function name is declared friend. When you mention Get(FriendIndex<1>) the name is injected, but the definition, which is necessary for function to be treated as constexpr can only come from instantiation of FriendInjector<1, true>. That doesn't happen until DelayedSideEffect requires its instantiation. Since it has a known int return type, nothing requires its instantiation until the end of the scope.

@Joshua Maiche -- what I find more interesting is that clang still considers Get function not constexpr after explicitly instantiating FriendInjector<1, true>. The other compilers are fine with that.
https://godbolt.org/z/Y7K3xd679

@Gene "nothing requires its instantiation until the end of the scope" seems really important. Is there anything in the standard that specifies when template instantiations' bodies will be visible, and how auto might change that?

@Gene For your godbolt example, I think that's just ADL shenanigans. I suspect auto dummy2 = Get(FriendIndex<1>{}); is somehow adding a separate Get() function in the global space, instead of in the FriendIndex space, where FriendInjector will define its Get() function.
Removing the dummy2 line entirely fixes the problem. It's unneeded since FriendInjector will already instantiate FriendIndex.

First of all, the standard does not distinguish between int and auto return types in a way that is relevant to your example. See [temp.inst]/3:

Unless a function template specialization has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the function template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a function definition to exist. Unless a call is to a function template explicit specialization or to a member function of an explicitly specialized class template, a default argument for a function template or a member function of a class template is implicitly instantiated when the function is called in a context that requires the value of the default argument.

When you actually call a function template specialization, the definition must exist. That definition is not necessarily required to be present in the same translation unit; it might be explicitly instantiated in a different translation unit. But, in cases where the definition is present in the same translation unit, a call triggers the implicit instantiation of the definition. So, in your case, both InstantSideEffect and DelayedSideEffect are instantiated when called, and that means the corresponding FriendInjector specializations are instantiated along with them.
However, implementations have latitude to defer instantiation of function template specializations until a later point in the translation unit under [temp.point]/8:

A specialization for a function template, a member function template, or of a member function or static data member of a class template may have multiple points of instantiations within a translation unit, and in addition to the points of instantiation described above, for any such specialization that has a point of instantiation within the translation unit, the end of the translation unit is also considered a point of instantiation. A specialization for a class template has at most one point of instantiation within a translation unit. A specialization for any template may have points of instantiation in multiple translation units. If two different points of instantiation give a template specialization different meanings according to the one definition rule ([basic.def.odr]), the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

The last sentence basically means that the house always wins. If you wrote code that depends on the point of instantiation being in one place and the implementation decides to put it somewhere else, then the implementation will reject your code or your code will behave differently than expected, which it is allowed to do because the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. If the implementation decided to put the point of instantiation where you were hoping, then the implementation will accept your code, which it is also allowed to do.
It seems that the implementations you've tested all use the strategy of deferring instantiation of DelayedSideEffect until the end of the translation unit, which means it is too late for Get(FriendIndex<1>{}) to be a constant expression at the point where the latter appears. But your program is IFNDR because its meaning changes depending on whether the instantiation is deferred.
On the other hand, templated functions that have a deduced return type will not have their instantiation deferred because the compiler needs to know the type of the function before it can continue semantic analysis.
Final note: The wording in the standard is not exactly right. It defines "point of instantiation", but the only normative meaning given to points of instantiation is that they control name lookup. Whether or not a function definition has been instantiated yet is not a name lookup issue. The last sentence of [temp.point]/8 means to give implementations broad latitude to defer instantiation, not only with respect to name lookup, so the wording does not quite reflect the intent.

Do I understand correctly, the "point of instantiation" is actually a point of potential instantiation, compiler is not required but allowed to instantiate at those points, and the program only becomes ill-formed if instantiating in different points produces ODR violations or changes the meaning of the program? Is the "point of instantiation" still considered even if instantiation at that point would produce hard error?

@Gene Even coneptually, if two POIs can result in ODR vilation, the program will be IFNDR.

@user12002570 -- even conceptually for ODR violation to exist in the first place you need to have two successful but different instantiations.

"successful but different instantiations...." Define successful and different here. Does successful mean no hard error etc? Also different how like say f<int>() and f<double>() or something else.

@Gene Mechanistically, yes, you can think of points of instantiation for functions as being points of potential instantiation. But according to the standard, the meaning is that instantiation takes place at all points of instantiation, and the instantiations at the multiple points are compared with each other, and if they are identical, the program behaves as if one of them is arbitrarily selected.

@Brian Bi -- so, if compiler actually performs every instantiation then it means that if any instantiation fails, then compilation should also fail. Is that correct?

@Gene Yes, but the compiler isn't actually required to perform the instantiation at every point because of how the standard uses IFNDR here.

@Brian Bi -- could you explain 13.9.2/5 (https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#5), which sounds like specifying the exact place of instantiation, when saying the function template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a function definition to exist or if the existence of the definition affects the semantics of the program -- It reads like the implementation is required to instantiate when the mentioned conditions are satisfied, neither before nor after that.

@Gene IFNDR overrides all other rules in the standard. If you have a program that is IFNDR, the compiler is always allowed to reject it (but is not required to), and does not need to tell you the "true" reason why it is rejecting your program. If the program is not IFNDR, then you won't be able to tell whether the compiler chose to defer instantiation.

@Brian Bi -- sorry, still have questions. The IFNDR in the quoted 14.6.4.1/8 is predicated on violation of ODR, no ODR violation = no IFNDR. In the OP code there is no possibility of ODR violation happening, no matter whether compiler delays instantiation or not. So following that logic the result should be implementation-specific, rather than IFNDR.

@Gene It says that if two different points of instantiation give the specialization different meanings "according to the one-definition rule" then the program is IFNDR. It is not just redundantly restating the ODR. It is saying that you have to consider the resulting specialization at each point of instantiation, and pretend that those multiple specializations are multiple definitions of one (inline) function in different translation units. And then if that hypothetical program violates the ODR, then the original program is IFNDR.
